# How to order this array from highest number to lowest number limited for 3 items?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

This is my array :

```
Array
(
[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [name] => fixed
                [total_kms] => 200
            )

    )

[9] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [name] => Temo
                [total_kms] => 550
            )

    )

[10] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [name] => mohamed mostafa
                [total_kms] => 1273
            )

    )

[11] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [name] => ahmed mostafa
                [total_kms] => 1122
            )

    )

    )
```

I want to display this array like this table but order this array from highest number to lowest number limited for 3 names

[image]

1. Display name
2. Display total_kms
3. order from highest number to lowest number
4. Limited for 3 names (table should content top 3 names have the top kilometers  )

my code for the table

```
<table class="table">
      <h4 class="text-muted">
       Top3 drivers done most kilometers
    </h4>
    <hr>
<tbody>
    <tr>
      <th class="thead-dark">Driver</th>
         for ($i=0; $i < count($driver_kms) ; $i++)
         {
           if ($driver_kms[$i]->name !='')
           {
              <td><?=$driver_kms[$i]->name?></td>
           }
          }
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <th>Kms</th>
         for ($i=0; $i < count($driver_kms) ; $i++)
            {
           if ($driver_kms[$i]->name !='')
           {
              <td><?=$driver_kms[$i]->total_kms?></td>
          }
          }
    </tr>

</tbody>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava only display this array into the table like the image

Comment: Please post your code attempt to achieve your goal. Otherwise it seems to be you are asking us to do code for you

Comment: @AlivetoDie i have posted my code

Comment: $driver_kms is my array name

Comment: is $driver_kms the result of a mysql query ?

Comment: while fetching from database why dont you use `order by  total_kms desc` and  `limit 3`

Comment: this my query code 
`$users = User::select('name as driver_name','id as user_id')->get();
foreach ($users as $value) {
   $driver_kms[$value->user_id] = DB::select("select users.name, SUM(reservations.meters) as total_kms from reservations left outer join users on (reservations.driver_id=users.id) where zone_id = $url_or_id and driver_id = $value->user_id and reservations.meters !=''  order by SUM(reservations.meters) DESC limit 3");
}
$driver_kms = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $driver_kms);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace

```
$users = User::select('name as driver_name','id as user_id')->get(); 
foreach   ($users as $value) { 
  $driver_kms[$value->user_id] = DB::select("select users.name,SUM(reservations.meters) as total_kms from reservations left outer join  ers on (reservations.driver_id=users.id) where zone_id = $url_or_id and driver_id = $value->user_id and reservations.meters !='' order by SUM(reservations.meters) DESC limit 3");
 } 
 $driver_kms = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $driver_kms);
```

with

```
$driver_kms = DB::select("select users.name, SUM(reservations.meters) as total_kms    
from reservations left outer join users 
on (reservations.driver_id = users.id) 
where zone_id = $url_or_id and reservations.meters !='' 
group by reservations.driver_id
order by SUM(reservations.meters) DESC limit 3");
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the expected result in a single query like :

```
SELECT U.name, SUM(R.meters) 
FROM users U, reservations R 
WHERE U.id = R.driver_id
ORDER BY SUM(R.meters) DESC
LIMIT 3
```

**OR**

Order your array with `arsort($driver_kms)` then limit your for loop to 3 elements `for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) { ...`

Answer (score -1):

Just use http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php
Use callback to compare your array elements.